# Rule in Moderncv

Tags: moderncv, rules

How can one generate a line/rule and the corresponding spacing to the text similar to the `\maketitle` command within the moderncv (casual) class?

What is the thickness and color of the rule in `\maketitle`. Using `\rule` adds to much space after the text. How can one achieve the same space between the text and the rule as in `\maketitle`.

Here a working example (compare first and second page):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[grey]{casual}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}

\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}       

\firstname{first}
\familyname{second}

%#########
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\newpage
\begin{flushright}
\Huge
\textcolor{gray}{Custom Header}\\
{\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your specific [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) theme, the header construction is contained within [`moderncvheadii.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvheadii.sty).

Here is an extract of the `\makecvhead` macro that replicates the "header" you wish to create:

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[grey]{casual}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}

\firstname{first}
\familyname{second}

%#########
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage

\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{%
  \raggedleft
  \namefont
  \textcolor{color2!50}{custom} \textcolor{color2}{header}%
}\\[-.35em]%
{\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}

\end{document}
```